# Reading mongo collection created outside of meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a mongo collection that is created outside of Meteor that holds user info of people who want access to my app. It looks like this in MongoVue-

```
**tmpUsers**

/* 5 */
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("54c7ae456587e23335915948"),
 "email" : "trial@domain.com",
 "first" : "Trial User",
 "type" : "trial",
 "active" : "Yes"
}
```

When I try to read this I get basically an empty collection structured like this -

```
collection: 
 d_docs: d._IdMap_..........
```

Here's my code -

```
**client**

    var type = "";
    var tmpCursor = tmpUsers.find({"email": Meteor.user().emails[0].address});
    tmpCursor.forEach(function(rec) {
        type = rec.type
    });
    Meteor.call("updateProfile", Meteor.userId(), type);

**server**

    Meteor.methods({
    "updateProfile": function(id, value){
        Meteor.users.update({"_id": id}, {$set: {"profile.acctType": value}});
    }
   })
```

How would I update the client side code to read the type from tmpUsers?

**Update:**

Here is where I insert the record from outside of Meteor -

```
        try {
        $mongoDb = $mongoConn->abcdefg;
        $collection = $mongoDb->tmpUsers;
        $userInfo = array("email" => $_POST['email'],  'first' => $first,"type" => $_POST['type'], 'active' => $activation);
        $collection->insert($userInfo);
    } catch (MongoException $e) {
        die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this.

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){ 
   Meteor.subscribe('tmpUsers',function(){ 
    var finde = tmpUsers.find({email:Meteor.user().emails[0].address}).count(); 
  if (finde === 1){ 
      console.log("found email"); 
   } else{ 
     console.log("not email found") 
    } 
 }); 
});
```

Comment: Not sure if I follow this. The database is external only to where I insert the record for tmpUsers. Where I try to read `type = rec.type` is where I can not get the type from tmpUsers.

Comment: so tmpUsers, is the external DB yes?

Comment: Yes, but only external on the php side. Meteor publishes and subscribes to it.

Comment: and if you run a find on the console, it works? are you sure the connection is done?

Comment: From the console the find works but does not map the field names like other finds do. Using MongoVue I can see that PHP get's them in the DB but I think this format causes the find to be empty `"_id" : ObjectId("54c7ae456587e23335915948")`, however if I use a PHP side function to create a random 17 character id the find still returns nothing. From the console this returns the email address that matches the value in tmpUsers - `Meteor.user().emails[0].address`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69844/discussion-between-leoj-pyzynski-and-ethaan).